# How to find the index sequence to sort a list?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list of float numbers which can have same values

```
List<float> l = new List<float>{1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 0};
```

And I want to get the index sequence to sort the list, which has the index of the least number first and the index of largest number last. For the above example, results are `{5, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2}`. For the same valued number, the order doesn't matter. Any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @WicherVisser That question is unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pair up elements with their index, sort pairs on the element, then harvest the index, like this:

```
var res = l.Select((v, i) => new {v, i})
    .OrderBy(p => p.v)
    .Select(p => p.i)
    .ToList();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2zYtfa)

Comment: Great! I am wondering (1) what is the type of new {v, i}? Is it pair? (2) Why compiler know i is index? Is it grammar described the second parameter is index? Thanks.

Comment: @user1899020 `new {v, i}` is an anonymous type ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)). Compiler creates it on the spot for use in this query. Compiler has no idea that `i` is an index, it's the `Select` overload that takes two-argument function that does ([this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx)).